# Somehow MySQL suddenly cant execute queries after this is ran

Tags: c#, mysql, database, image, dataset

```
public void saveImage(byte[] image, int patient_id, MySqlConnection con)
    {
        string sql = "select * from patient where id ="+patient_id;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("patient");
        MySqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
        dAdapter.Fill(ds, "patient2");
        try
        {
            ds.Tables["patient2"].Rows[0]["picture"] = image;
            dAdapter.Update(ds, "patient2");

            // ds.Tables["patient2"].Rows[0].AcceptChanges();


            con.Close();
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception exs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exs.Message);
        }

    }
```

How could i fix this error... after this is executed none of the following queries will work after that... what happened? i already tried commenting the "con.close" and "con.open" either way still,...

Comment: no specific errors... its just that none of the next queries would run.. its like mysql just turned itself off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this happens because you close the connection, then reopen it. You're not supposed to reopen a closed connection... actually I'm surprised it doesn't throw an `InvalidOperationException`. And anyway, if your method receives an open connection as a parameter, it shouldn't close it. The code that opens the connection is responsible for closing it.

Comment: i found out that the image is more than 1.5MB and im using LONGBLOB, found out that the client is being disconnected and mysql has gone away due to that issue... try to rmeove open and close see waht happens... ill edit my post later...